# PHP Array search

Tags: php, arrays, search

I need a search system with arrays :

```
        $ArrayNotes = array 
            (
              0 => array ('titre' => 'Hello all','ref' => 'aa','date' => 'aa','like' => 0,'url' => 'aa',),
              1 => array ('titre' => 'Hello the world','ref' => 'aa','date' => 'aa','like' => 0,'url' => 'aa',),
            );
```

If in the array it contains "Hello" so I hope it shows me the two arrays : Hello all & Hello the world.

Exemple :

```
//For example :
       // In my url : ?search=Hello OR ?search=Hel
        $my_var_search = $_POST['search'];
        array_search($ArrayNotes,$my_var_search);

    foreach ($ArrayNotes as $key => $row ) 
     {
       $my_var_search = $_POST['search'];
       array_search($ArrayNotes,$my_var_search);
       echo $titre[$key];
      }
```

Display :

Hello all & Hello the world

Thanks you for the help !

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? If so, please include your code and possible errors that you got in the question.

Comment: Post your expected output along with your attempts

Comment: look the example, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This prints out an array containing the original array rows where 'titre"  contains "Hello" needle.

```
 $ArrayNotes = array 
            (
              0 => array ('titre' => 'Hello all','ref' => 'aa','date' => 'aa','like' => 0,'url' => 'aa',),
              1 => array ('titre' => 'Hello the world','ref' => 'aa','date' => 'aa','like' => 0,'url' => 'aa',),
              2 => array ('titre' => 'Not contain the word','ref' => 'aa','date' => 'aa','like' => 0,'url' => 'aa',),
            );
$arrayOk = array();
$hello = "Hello";
for ($i=0; $i<count($ArrayNotes);$i++) {
    if (stristr($ArrayNotes[$i]['titre'],$hello)) {
        $arrayOk[$i] = $ArrayNotes[$i];
    }
        }
print_r($arrayOk);
```

to print out:

```
foreach ($arrayOk as $value) {
    echo $value['titre']." ";
}
```